# Android Studio 3.0 Beta2: Gradle check does not work anymore

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading from *Android Studio 3.0 **Canary 5*** to *Android Studio 3.0 **Beta2***, the Gradle check task in Android Studio fails.

Notes:

- it works fine in the command line: e.g. `gradlew.bat check`
- other Gradle tasks also work from within the IDE: e.g. *testDebugUnitTest*,  *build*, .. 
  [image]
- I've already tried to restart the PC, invalidate caches, increase the gradle memory in `gradle.properties` (to 4GB)

The error symptoms:

- The project is quite big and has many modules
- When I start the check task from the IDE, I can see in the *Gradle Console*, that the sub-modules are build correctly and the build just stops after `testDebugUnitTest` of the android app
- the Messages dialogue just shows `Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: unknown.`

I've tried to change the run-configuration and added the `--debug --stacktrace` parameters. The log-output is also not really helpful (for me).
Here are the last lines (full version is [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tmtron/4faaea62cb0ec3d4009f361f21bc456e/raw/6bb87bc42a5bf56ef93ccc98f056cbb6cce9f2ef/gistfile1.txt))

```
12:32:25.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.33.1937.1943 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
12:32:25.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] build operations: released lock on root.1.33.1937.1943
12:32:25.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Resolve files of :m10_android_app:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'
12:32:25.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 685: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildEvent
12:32:25.560 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve files of :m10_android_app:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath' completed
12:32:25.561 [QUIET] [system.out] 
12:32:25.561 [QUIET] [system.out]
```

Comment: still the same issue in the AS 3.0 release version

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?  I'm on AS 3.0.1, still seeing this issue on one of my projects.

Comment: unfortunately not - it still does not work for me. As a workaround, I've created a batch script which I can execute in the Terminal window.